# GridView problem with useless scrollbar in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, gridview

I have a problem, I use a gridView and it has totally the place to display my 4 elements, but still puts me a scroll bar that allows me to see the end of my last elements when it could display them directly to me.

My GridView :

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<GridView
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/about_grid_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numColumns="2"/>

<View
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="4dp"
    android:background="@color/colorRedLogoDark" />
```

And I need to display some elements underneath, but I'd like to remove the useless scroll bar.
I would like to point out that my element instead of displaying everything.